# Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS) header not present in response when making request with an expired token

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm buliding an app using spring-security-oauth2. In general, everything is working fine and I have three independent clients using a simple API I have created. All client apps are calling the API from different domains. All the apps can register members using the client-credentials grant, and then get password grant access tokens and refresh tokens.

However, for all three clients, when a request is sent using an expired access token, the response from the resource server does not include an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. This is a problem for the hal-browser and angular app as they rely on responses having an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

What is the spring way of including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the expired token response?

I have a Filter adding the following headers on a zuul gateway, but the filter never gets fired in the case of a request with an expired access token.

```
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, HEAD");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "X-Requested-With, WWW-Authenticate, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Version");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
            "X-Requested-With, WWW-Authenticate, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After diving into the spring code, it turned out this issue was caused by the order of filter execution. The OAuth filter was called first and threw an InvalidAccessToken exception, preventing my CORS filter from ever running and adding the necessary Acccess-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Adding the annotation

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

to my CORS filter did the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've spent all day on this problem